# How can I set a jsonarray inside the jsonobject?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I set a jsonarray inside the jsonobject?
I want to be able to push the values ​​but I do not know exactly what to do
sample :

```
{
 "ContactsDetails": [
 {
 "Prefix": "string",
 "FirstName": "string",
 "LastName": "string",
 "Mobile": "string",
 "EmojiId": "byte"
 }
],
 "GroupId": integer
}
```

Comment: whatever yo're doing is right.

Comment: Are you trying to set a new array inside the object, or push a new array as a new parameter?

Comment: @GalAbra Yes I want to create a jsonobject like a sample

Comment: There's no "jsonarrays" or "jsonobjects" in JavaScript. JSON is a language-independent textual data interchange format.

Comment: So just go through the JS object and array definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code what you're looking for.

```js
let empty = {}; // init a empty object. 

empty["ContactsDetails"] = []; // array creation 

empty["GroupId"] = 45; // number adding

// creating a new object 
let c_details = {
  "Prefix": "string",
  "FirstName": "string",
  "LastName": "string",
  "Mobile": "string",
  "EmojiId": "byte"
};

// adding an existing obj to array, push operation 
empty["ContactsDetails"].push(c_details);

// print object 
console.log(empty);

// this will convert the object to JSON. 
console.log(JSON.stringify(empty))
```

Comment: {
  "Message": "Text",
  "MobileNumbers": [
    Mobile
  ],
  "CanContinueInCaseOfError": true
} ---- Need help with this

Comment: let empty = {};
empty["Message"] = "Random text";
empty["MobileNumbers"] = [];
let mobile_numbers = [ "Mobile" ];
empty["MobileNumbers"].push(mobile_numbers);
empty["CanContinueInCaseOfError"] = true;
console.log(empty);

Answer (score 0):

What you call a *JSONArray* is simply a Javascript array like `[]`. You can set it like any property of an Object (JSON).

In Javascript, an `Object` (symbolized as `{}`) will be represented as a JSON Object and a `Array` (symbolized by `[]`) will be represented as a JSON Array.

So you can just do something like this :

```js
var object = {};

object.foo = [];

object.foo.push("newvalue");
object.foo.push("bar");

console.log(object);
```

And of course, you can `push` an Object in your array like this :

```js
var array = [];

array.push({ foo: "bar" });

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays** and **objects** are structures that can recursively contain themselves, or each other. JSON is just a format that represents these recursive data structures.

Luckily, you can define all of these in JavaScript using plain literals:

- An array literal is wrapped within brackets `[]`
- An object literal is wrapped within curly brackets `{}`

Hence, you can build an array of objects:

```
[
    {name: 'x', data: 0},
    {name: 'y', data: 1}
]
```

Or an object that its parameters are arrays:

```
{
    array0: [0, 1],
    array1: [2, 3]
}
```

And, as I mentioned above, you can also use these structures recursively. For example:

```
[
    {id: 0, array: [0, 1]},
    {id: 1, array: [2, 3]}
]
```